# Pattern by means of function

Tags: c

The problem is: [image]

What i have done: [image]

I have used 2 1 0 instead of + - ' ' respectivly.This problem must be done by means of function.
But, these don't match the output given. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Please start here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Don't post pictures, post code. And you're printing numbers `%d`, not characters `%c`.

Comment: @Unimportant, i mentioned it, its more understandable for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Here you are. The code is written in C++. So you need to investigate it and rewrite it in C yourself.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Input the number of elements : ";

        unsigned int n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << "Input the size of each element : ";

        unsigned int m;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> m ) or ( m == 0 ) ) break;

        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < m + 2; i++  )
        {
            char c1 = i == 0 || i == m + 1 ? '+' : '|';
            char c2 = i == 0 || i == m + 1 ? '-' : ' ';

            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < n + m * ( n - 1 ); j++ )
            {
                std::cout << ( j % (m + 1) == 0 ? c1 : c2 );  
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
Input the number of elements : 10
Input the size of each element : 3

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

Input the number of elements : 0
```